# how to get index of the clicked cell in array containing tr tags with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I'm developing an online registration system for an ISP. In this project, I want to get the index of the clicked cell in prices table. In the last row of the table I only have links to registration page. When a user clicks on the link, the information of his/her slelected service would be sent to registration page by using get method. I can handle this but my problem is I can't get the index of the selected link's container cell. I mean when I use this code : 
 `var rows = document.getElementById("myTable").rows;` 
 after executing, 'rows' should be a 2-dimensional array containing rows and cells of the table. What I'm trying to achieve now, is to when a user clicks on a the link inside a cell, I can access the selected cell's index in the `rows` array. How can I achieve this?

Comment: As this has nothing to do with PHP, I've removed the tag for you.

Comment: Sadly, the reality is that with any JavaScript question related to browser code, you need to be explicit about whether you're using jQuery or not. People tend to assume you are even if you don't say you are (they shouldn't, but they do).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unclear to me whether you want the index of the cell in the row, or the row in the table, or both, so this covers both:

You can find the containing `td` and use its [`cellIndex` property](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#dom-tdth-cellindex); and find its containing `tr` and use its [`rowIndex` property](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#dom-tr-rowindex):

```
function yourClickHandler(e) {
    var node = e.target;
    while (node && node.tagName !== "TR") {
        if (node.tagName === "TD" || node.tagName === "TH") {
            console.log("The cell's index is " + node.cellIndex);
        }
        node = node === node.tagName === "TABLE" ? null : node.parentNode;
    }
    if (node) {
        console.log("Row's index is " + node.rowIndex);
    }
}
```

Example:

```js
function yourClickHandler(e) {
    var node = e.target;
    while (node && node.tagName !== "TR") {
        if (node.tagName === "TD" || node.tagName === "TH") {
            console.log("The cell's index is " + node.cellIndex);
        }
        node = node === node.tagName === "TABLE" ? null : node.parentNode;
    }
    if (node) {
        console.log("Row's index is " + node.rowIndex);
    }
}
document.getElementById("the-table").addEventListener("click", yourClickHandler, false);
```

```css
table, td {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table id="the-table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="#">test</a></td>
      <td><a href="#">test</a></td>
      <td><a href="#">test</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="#">test</a></td>
      <td><a href="#">test</a></td>
      <td><a href="#">test</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="#">test</a></td>
      <td><a href="#">test</a></td>
      <td><a href="#">test</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="#">test</a></td>
      <td><a href="#">test</a></td>
      <td><a href="#">test</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="#">test</a></td>
      <td><a href="#">test</a></td>
      <td><a href="#">test</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. When I add this code to my project, and check it with Firefox "inspect element" console tab it returns "TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null". I have another javascript code in my page and it returns the same for that.

Comment: What if I have more than one tables? Should I use getElementsByTagName("Table")? In the console tab it also returns "TypeError: document.getElementsByTagName(...).addEventListener is not a function"

Comment: @rthenamvar: The `getElementById` above is purely for the example. In your own code, you'll need to identify the element or elements on which you want to hook the `click` event based on the structure of your HTML. Re the error you're getting trying to use `addEventListener` on the result of `getElementsByTagName`: [*What do querySelectorAll, getElementsByClassName and other getElementsBy\* methods return?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-getelementsbyclassname-and-other-getelementsby-method)

Comment: How can I identify the elements on which I want the "click" event to be triggered? I searched everywhere and there wasn't any special thing to do for that. Only giving an id to the element is what every website has said. Like in here : 
https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_addeventlistener_add

Comment: @rthenamvar: [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector), [`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName), [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName), ...

Comment: So many thanks for your response again. But now I'm not using 'getElementsByTagName', I'm just using 'getElementById' as you did. You said I have to identify the elements I'd like to be triggered on click. How can I do that when I'm only using 'getElementById'???

Answer (score 0):

When user clicks on specific button, then the current row index will be stored in `index` variable. Hope this is what you need.

```
(function(){
    // `.button-class` is a button on which user clicks to add service.
    $('.button-class').on('click', function() {
      var index = $(this).closest('tr').index();
    })
})();
```

Comment: jQuery answers to non-jQuery questions are not useful.